# Sharing my cognos reports with my peers

Tags: report, cognos, cognos-10

I am using cognos 10.2 . I have generated some reports as administrator in report studio. Now I want to share those reports with my peers. When I share the URL of the report I generated, its asking for username and password. I created a user and gave them those credentials. When they opened the link with those credentials, it shows the whole list of packages which I created. I don't want that to happen. I just want my peers to see only one report which I give them. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you need to read the administrator's guide.  You are missing some pretty basic concepts here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Cognos Connection, open the report's Properties. On the right-hand side there is a link to 'View the search path, ID and URL'. If you click on this link, a popup appears; you can copy the value under 'Default Action URL' and provide that to your peers, and it will link directly to your report.